# How to update this configmap with kubectl patch command, without kubectl edit command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Below is a `k8s` `configmap` configuration, I need to use the `kubectl patch` command to update it, but don't know how to do it

```
# kubectl get configmap myconfig -o yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: debug-config
data:
  config.json: |-
    {
        "portServiceDMS": 500,
        "Buggdse": {
            "Enable": false
        },
        "GHInterval": {
            "Start": 5062,
            "End": 6000
        },
        "LOPFdFhd": false,
        "CHF": {
            "DriverName": "mysql"
        },
        "Paralbac": {
            "LoginURL": "https://127.0.0.1:7788",
            "Sources": [
                {
                    "ServiceName": "Hopyyu",
                    "Status": false,
                    "ServiceURL": "https://127.0.0.1:9090/ft/test"
                },
                {
                    "SourceName": "Bgudreg",
                    "Status": false, # need to patch here to true
                    "ServiceURL": "https://127.0.0.1:9090"  # need to patch here to  "https://192.168.123.177:45663"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I searched on `google` site to find a similar way to deal with [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578789/kubectl-patch-is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-values-to-an-array-within-a-sinlge), but it doesn't work

I tried this command and it doesn't work：

```
kubectl get cm myconfig -o json | jq -r '.data."config.json".Paralbac.Sources[1]={"SourceName": "Bgudreg", "Status": true, "ServiceURL": "https://192.168.123.177:45663"}' | kubectl apply -f -
```

I reduced the command to here：

```
kubectl get cm myconfig -o json | jq -r '.data."config.json" # it works (The double quotes are for escaping the dot)

kubectl get cm myconfig -o json | jq -r '.data."config.json".Paralbac # it can't work：   jq: error (at <stdin>:18): Cannot index string with string "Paralbac"
```

So, I think my current problem is in how to keep working after `escaped` symbols in `jq`

Comment: For the `patch` problem, what have you tried and what outcome is it producing for you? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for the tip, I've updated what I've tried to above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can update the ConfigMap in the question:

```
myconfig=$(mktemp) \
  && kubectl get configmap debug-config -o jsonpath='{.data.config\.json}' \
  | jq '.Paralbac.Sources[1].Status = true' \
  | jq '.Paralbac.Sources[1].ServiceURL = "https://192.168.123.177:45663"' > myconfig \
  && kubectl create configmap debug-config --from-file=config.json=myconfig --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl replace -f - \
  && rm myconfig
```

Now do `kubectl get configmap debug-config -o jsonpath='{.data.config\.json}' | jq` will show you the updated **config.json** in the ConfigMap.

Comment: Thanks @gohm'c, I think your answer is on point.